# How to use GnuPlot to plot a time series chart from a CSV file date and time stored in separate columns with double quote?

Tags: csv, gnuplot

I would like to plot data with x data as a time value.
The csv file looks as following

```
"","12/09/29","00:19:43","  1787","    12","12"
"","12/09/29","00:19:48","  1787","    12","12"
"","12/09/29","00:19:53","  1785","    13","12"
"","12/09/29","00:19:58","  1785","    12","12"
```

The problem here is the usage of the double quote. I tried this

```
set timefmt '"%y/%m/%d","%H:%M:%S"'
set datafile separator ","
plot 'myFile.csv' using 2:3:4 with lines
```

but it doesn't recognize the time format.

How can I recognize the time value from two separated column, with double quote and comma separator?

Thank you for your help.

thomas

Answer (score 2):

If quotes are the problem, and you're on a posix system with pipes enabled, you can easily remove them:

```
plot '< sed -e s/\"//g test.dat' using 2:4:5
```

Note that the `using` specification also changed (`2:4:5` instead of `2:3:4`) since your timeformat takes **2 columns**.

---

Note that I do not think that the quotes are problematic:

```
set datafile sep ','
set xdata time
set timefmt '%y/%m/%d,%H:%M:%S'  #no quotes in timefmt -- Gnuplot removes them when parsing the datafile.
plot 'test.dat' using 2:4:5 with lines
```

works for me.

So I really think that the problem was your using specification pointing at the third column (which contains time information) instead of the fourth.  Finally, you can make the same plot with `using 2:4` -- You never actually use the 5th column for anything here.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.

I tried your last proposition on my original data (with double quote), and I get an error:

    gnuplot> set xdata time
    gnuplot> set datafile sep ','
    gnuplot> set timefmt '"%y/%m/%d","%H:%M:%S"'
    gnuplot> plot 'essai.txt' using 2:4 with lines  
    Warning: empty x range [0:0], adjusting to [-1:1] 

The date shown is around 2000/01/01, instead of 2012/09/29.

I'm using gnuplot V4.6 on windows XP (french version): is there a problem with local settings?
Any idea ?

Sorry for the poor layout, I'm not used with these comments.

thomas

Comment: You're right.  I forgot `set xdata time` in my script so gnuplot was just parsing the 12 and I didn't look close enough to notice.  The point still remains though.  The case I have posted I've tested (more carefully this time) and it seems to work on gnuplot 4.4.2